# How can I access props in BootstrapTable dataFormat method

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-table, dataformat

I am working on React/Redux application and I am using the BootstrapTable as well.

In the dataFormat method I need to pass the props as well? right now my format method looks like:

```
function linkFormatter(cell, row) {
   //Logic
}
```

I tried using:

```
let self = this;
```

to access the props as `this.props.isStatatusActive` but it also gave me the error : `isStatatusActive is undefined.`

Any recommendations?

Comment: can you provide some more context

Comment: what more information do u need ?

Comment: If your question is: "How can I format extra data using dataFormat?", then [this link](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/advance.html) will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to have access to not only the **cell** and the **row** of the table but also your props, there is a really good example in [this article](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/advance.html).

`formatExtraData` is what you are looking for.

```
function enumFormatter(cell, row, enumObject){
return enumObject[cell];
}

export default class ExtraDataColumnFormatTable extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <BootstrapTable data={products} >
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name">Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="quality" dataFormat={enumFormatter} formatExtraData={qualityType}>Product Quality</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="inStock" dataFormat={enumFormatter} formatExtraData={inStockStatus}>Product Stock Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
        );
    }
};
```

You could probably send `this.props. directly in that method:

`formatExtraData={this.props}`

And then your formatter would look like:

```
function formatter(cell, row, props) {
    // Logic
}
```